# HTTP Error 429 on Linux server, but not my local machine?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, urllib, pytube

I'm running a Python program that downloads one single video from YouTube every hour using Pytube onto my local machine and I have no problems with it at all. However, when I deploy the same program onto my Linux server, I receive the following error:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Does anyone know why this is or what I can do to fix it? I'm using a Linode Shared CPU running Ubuntu 21.10.

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/main.py", line 137, in <module>
    main_function()
  File "/root/main.py", line 131, in main_function
    get_screenshot()
  File "/root/main.py", line 60, in get_screenshot
    video = youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 291, in streams
    self.check_availability()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 206, in check_availability
    status, messages = extract.playability_status(self.watch_html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 98, in watch_html
    self._watch_html = request.get(url=self.watch_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/request.py", line 53, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Comment: youtube probably blocks the ip range of popular public clouds

Comment: @AnthonySottile is probably on money. You could changed the server's ip (or launch a new one) and send a simple request to `"https://www.youtube.com/"` to check the status, e.g. `http "https://www.youtube.com/"` (using `httpie`).

Comment: @niko any suggestions on changing the server IP? I already tried launching a new server and I experienced the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your post and comment I would conclude that Youtube blocks request coming from linode (and probably also most cloud providers).

Unfortunately there is no easy solution, but here are a few ideas:

### 1.a. Cloud providers (Linode) with Proxy

Keep using linode and use a proxy (this is fairly easy using Python's `requests` module). There are many *free* proxies, but often time the latency is quite significant. Also, sometimes connections timeout or aren't processed for some other reason.

You can use pools of proxies in order to have alternatives in case of high latency or other problems.

Also bear in mind using (public) proxies <s>can be</s> is a security hazard. So I'd be *extremely* careful with the information sent (i.e. no passwords etc).

### 1.b. GCP

Google has its own cloud provider, *GCP*. The prices are typically somewhat higher than their counterparts. But it might just be that Youtube doesn't block GCP (being both Google). They might be on some shared network. So that might be worth testing.

### 2. Bare Metal

As you pointed, your home machine is able to run your script. So you could let your home system run as a home server.

Alternatively, you could also use a singleboard computer (e.g. Raspberry Pi): these have typically a very low power consumption, they're cheap, can run 24/7 and support most software typically required (Python, Docker, etc.).